# XPath convert to JSoup Elements

Tags: java, jsoup

I need to catch a few information about weather.I used JSoup, but I have a problem with convert my xPath to Elements . Do you know why?? I'm a bit confused.

I created this code

```
        String newUrl= new String("http://www.weather.com/wx/today/?lat="+lat+"&lon="+lon+"+&locale=en_US");
        String tmpS=new String("http://www.weather.com/wx/today/?lat=52.450988049&lon=20.66802978515625&locale=en_US"); 
        URL example = new URL(tmpS);
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(example.openStream()));

        StringBuilder websiteSource = new StringBuilder();
        String tmp = null;
        while ((tmp = in.readLine()) != null) {
            websiteSource.append(tmp);
        }
        in.close();

        System.out.println(websiteSource.toString());

        Document doc = Jsoup.parse(websiteSource.toString());

        ////*[@id="wx-local-wrap"]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/article/div/div/article/div/section[1]/section[1]/div[1]/div
        Elements h1Elements = doc.select("#wx-local-wrap > div:eq(1) > div:eq(1) > div> div > article > div > selection > selection > div > div")
```

Comment: You can try to investigate requests to weather.com using fiddler2. May be you can do direct request for getting needed data.

Answer (score 1):

The content of this site is generated by javascript.They are using Angular.js to be exact. Jsoup can't handle that. You have to use something like [selenium webdriver](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/projects/webdriver/), so you can run the javascript code, this will cause the actual content to be generated and then parse that. At that point, when the content is generated you can use jsoup to parse it.